# Reference for preimage of boundary of spacefilling curve

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, curves-and-surfaces

Given a continuous map $\gamma$ from $[0,1]$ onto a bounded
contractible subset $S$ of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $S$ contains an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which is dense in $S$,
the preimage $\gamma^{-1}(\partial S)$ of the boundary $\partial S$
should morally be a Cantor set in $[0,1]$ (this should be true for
'natural' examples (Peano curve and its variation by Hilbert,
Heighway dragon etc.) but it is easy to make up somewhat artificial examples where
$\gamma^{-1}(\partial S)$ contains isolated points and open intervals).

*Is there a reference where this problem has been treated?*